# Concatenate only extant non-empty numpy arrays?

Tags: arrays, numpy, concatenation

This should be easy...

I want to concatenate arrays A, B and C. It is possible that one or more of them may not exist or be empty. I want the remaining arrays to be concatenated. If, for example, B is empty, I want to concatenate A with C.

I've read these questions that seem relevant:

[How can I check whether the numpy array is empty or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295609/how-can-i-check-whether-the-numpy-array-is-empty-or-not)

[How do you 'remove' a numpy array from a list of numpy arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157374/how-do-you-remove-a-numpy-array-from-a-list-of-numpy-arrays)

I assume there's a 1-2 line way to do this.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "may not exist"?

Comment: A, B and C are arrays from a list, and I may be taking an out-of-range index. But to keep this more general, any situation where A, B and/or C may not have been generated.

Answer (score 4):

Concatenating empty arrays is not a problem:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(10)

In [2]: b = np.array([])

In [3]: c = np.arange(3)

In [4]: np.concatenate((a,b,c))
Out[4]: array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.,  0.,  1.,  2.])
```

For 2D arrays:

```
In [1]: a = np.arange(12.0).reshape((4,3))

In [2]: b = np.arange(24.0).reshape((8,3))

In [3]: c = np.array([])

In [4]: np.concatenate([x for x in [a,b,c] if x.size > 0])
Out[4]: 
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.],
       [  0.,   1.,   2.],
       [  3.,   4.,   5.],
       [  6.,   7.,   8.],
       [  9.,  10.,  11.],
       [ 12.,  13.,  14.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.],
       [ 18.,  19.,  20.],
       [ 21.,  22.,  23.]])
```

Comment: I know that, but these aren't 1D arrays, except if they're empty.

Comment: @TristanKlassen: What shape are the arrays? If they aren't 1D then you  should also specify exactly what you mean when you say "concatenate".

Comment: 2D. Concatenate along the axis where they're guaranteed to be the same size except if they're empty.

Comment: @user545424 - did you skip the part in the explanation about the arrays being numpy?

Comment: @StefanH, well the question is tagged [numpy].

Comment: I get a " ValueError: concatenation of zero-length sequences is impossible ". I believe one of the input arrays doesn't exist, but this sounds like it's due to all of A, B and C being empty. I had to add exception handling for this.

Comment: @TristanKlassen, please edit your original question and give a concrete example of arrays `a`, `b`, and `c` that you would like to be able to handle, and what you expect to get out.